# Event tracking: Hits from Firefox, Chrome not being recorded, only MSIE

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Event Tracking to keep track of clicks to download a PDF file. It is working great, BUT IT ONLY REGISTERS HITS FROM MSIE, not Firefox, Chrome.
I have even instituted the "time delay" suggested before the click registers, which was suggested in these forums... Still not working.

Here is a code line:

```
<a href="http://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/146/pdf/gip_146_poster.pdf" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cycle-Kids', 'English', 'PDF']);">PDF</a>
```

Here is one with a time delay:

```
<a href="watercyclekids/download/watercycle-kids-german.pdf" onClick="var that=this;_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cycle-Kids', 'German', 'PDF']);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},800);return false;">PDF</a>
```

Comment: why not add a target="_blank" and have the pdf open in a separate window? IMO this is better UX and also you won't even have to worry about the delay.  This may or may not actually solve your problem though.. at face value there is nothing wrong with your code.  Only thing I can think of is maybe you have some other code that is overwriting the onclick event - but that other code is failing in IE

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to say, yes, we tried target="_blank". Still won't register Firefox, etc. Very strange, indeed.